# Finding the maxima of a given function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, maxima-minima, dimensional-analysis

Please look into the following question. I have solved Part (a). For part (b) I found $f_{\pi_{2}}$ and $f_{\pi_{3}}$, where $f_{\pi_{2}}$ stands for the partial of $f$ with respect to $\pi_{2}$. I found that there are 4 critical points $(1/2,1/2); (1/2,0); (0,1/2); (1/3,1/3)$. Here, $f=\pi_{1}^{2}$.

Among them first 3 cannot happen, otherwise it will cause $0$ in the denominator of $F$. So, the only option is $(1/3,1/3)$, which makes the triangle equilateral.

I am stuck with the last part of (b).." Explain why .......is a triangular region". and Part (c).

How do I approach these 2 problems? Please, any hints will be appreciated. For part (c), will it be ok, if I calculate using basic geometry the area of equilateral triangle and the corresponding circumscribed circle and then proceed to calculate $\pi_{1}$ for 2 different cases, thereby establishing the inequality mentioned in the question at the end?

**Problem:**
[image]

Comment: If you are ok, you can accept the answer and set as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

For point b note that $\Pi_2$ and $\Pi_3$ have to satisfy the following inequalities

$$\left(\frac12-\Pi_2\right)\left(\frac12-\Pi_3\right)\left(\Pi_2+\Pi_3-\frac12\right)\ge0$$

$$0\leq\Pi_2\le1\quad 0\leq\Pi_3\le1 \quad \frac12\leq\Pi_2+\Pi_3\le1$$

Comment: Thanks for Part (b). For Part (c), is using basic geometry alright, or is there any other way?

Comment: @For Part (c) once you have the minimum value simply compare it with $4\pi$.